# Div doesn't Animate after stop()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is, whenever we leave the button and then move back to the grey content box, the slideUp will stop and the content will be slideDown again.

It works just fine using **jQuery 1.x (edge)**, but when I use **jQuery 1.10** the slideUp just stop, and not continue to slideDown again.

Do you guys have any idea which part should I change to make it work on **jQuery 1.10**?

```
$(function () {
    var show_content = '';

    $('.nav-content > div').hide();

    $('.btn1,.btn2').mouseenter(function (e) {
        var target = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class');
        console.log('Mouse Enter : ' + target);

        if (target == 'btn1') {
            show_content = $('.con1');
        } else if (target == 'btn2') {
            show_content = $('.con2');
        }
        show_content.stop().slideDown(300);
    });

    $('.btn1,.btn2').mouseleave(function (e) {
        var target = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class');
        show_content.stop().slideUp(2000);

    });

    $('.nav-content').mouseenter(function (e) {
        show_content.stop().slideDown(300);

    });
    $('.nav-content').mouseleave(function (e) {
        show_content.stop().slideUp(2000, 'swing', function (e) {
            console.log('Hide done');
        });
    });

});
```

Here's my Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/PmJt2/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out why not continue to slideDown again, but slideToggle works.

Use `.slideToggle()` instead of slideDown and slideUp

Comment: Thanks alot mate.. `slideToggle()` do the trick. But still wondering how to continue it though.. Tried pretty much all stop() true false combination and none of it works. But I guess slideToggle will do for now.